# Get the number value after the character

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string like this:

```
 Executed 29 of 31 (3 FAILED) (skipped 2) (0.283 secs / 0.08 secs)
```

I want to get the value after `skipped`. But if I give the regex as:

```
/skipped/
```

it only matches the `skipped` character, but I want to get the number `2` after that.

How to do this in javascript?

Comment: Use capturing groups `/skipped (\d+)/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
skipped\s+(\d+)
```

Try this.Grab the capture or group.

See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rG7gX4/9

```
var re = /skipped\s+(\d+)/gmi;
var str = 'Executed 29 of 31 (3 FAILED) (skipped 2) (0.283 secs / 0.08 secs)';
var m;

while ((m = re.exec(str)) != null) {
if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
re.lastIndex++;
}
// View your result using the m-variable.
// eg m[0] etc.
}
```